# Set Javascript object value at time of creation

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is it possible to set one object's key `$thumbnailContainer` to the value of another object `thumbnailImg` within the same object `gallerySelectors`?

Example:

```
var gallerySelectors = {
    '$thumbnailContainer' : $('#thumb'),
    'thumbnailImg' : this.$thumbnailContainer.find('img')
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because `this` will not be bound to the object in the situation you show.

I don't think there is a way to do this.

You could try

```
var gallerySelectors = {
    '$thumbnailContainer' : $('#thumb'),
    'thumbnailImg' : gallerySelectors.$thumbnailContainer.find('img')
};                     ^--------------- NOTE!!!
```

but I'm not sure whether I would trust this to work everywhere. I guess you'd have to look into the language spec to see whether the members are always guaranteed to be initialized in order.

I would just take the easy route:

```
var gallerySelectors = {
    '$thumbnailContainer' : $('#thumb'),
    'thumbnailImg' : $('#thumb').find('img')
};
```

Comment: I'm sure you didn't mean to type this:
`$('#thumb').$thumbnailContainer.find('img')`

Comment: Bummer. Thanks anyway. This is the method that I was probably going to end up doing.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately, there isn't. Luckily, the alternative is just as simple:

```
var gallerySelectors = {
    $thumbnailContainer: $('#thumb')
};

gallerySelectors.thumbnailImg = gallerySelectors.$thumbnailContainer.find('img');
```

You could also make a function to do that for you if the issue is that you want to pass the object inline.